# How can I read opencv images into caffe format for real-time prediction?

Tags: c++, opencv, caffe

I try to create a real-time prediction program from video frames. All the code is backended by opencv. However, I trained a caffe model and I try to use it by this [windows port](https://github.com/niuzhiheng/caffe) of caffe. It does not support opencv to caffe conversion of the images in memory. How can I do it externally? In the original caffe there is a solution that is [recently merged](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/80c9a2c17f5469371b434fde4072bc13b49ee1eb) but cannot apply this to this windows version.

Comment: maybe you should give a look at `ReadImageToDatum` from io.cpp and find a way to adapt it to your problem  ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to define the input to your network using a **[MEMORY_DATA](https://github.com/niuzhiheng/caffe/blob/windows/src/caffe/layers/memory_data_layer.cpp)** layer, then, using the `Reset` method you should be able to set the input according to the data stored in your opencv representation.